# My toilet bowl fill jets do not work

Tags: plumbing, toilet

When I flush my toilet the water fills the bowl from the bottom and is accompanied by bubbles.. No water comes out of the bowl jets to rinse the bowl and flush down.. I have researched and cleaned the jet holes. Water flows freely from the fill tube into the overflow tube freely. The flap works fine. No tubes are kinked and flapper is not obstructed.

Comment: If it's an old toilet then the jets may have become filled with crud.

Comment: If you have hard water and you've cleaned out the jet holes, the passage around the rim to the jet holes might be plugged with minerals (or other crud.) Cleaning it may be possible, but the labor involved might make you want to think about a new toilet (and depending on what your old toilet is, a new one might save you a LOT of water on flushes.)

Comment: Is this a new problem  or an old one?

Comment: Have you looked down the overflow tube to see if perhaps something fell in there and is blocking water flow from reaching the rim jets... not likely but worth a look with a flashlight.

Answer (score 1):

Someone may have dropped something down the overflow tube or flush hole that has clogged the bowl's rim feed for the bowl jets...can happen with mostly dissolved tank tablets.

This clog can also happen from plunging. Toilet paper can be forced backwards and up into the tank via the bowl's bottom front hole. Try vacuuming (best option), snaking or poking inside the flapper's flush hole.

Otherwise, you may have to remove the tank (if a 2-piece toilet) and shoot a garden hose or blow compressed air into the bowl jets if all else fails. Finally, buy a new $100-ish toilet...they're quite good toilets.